# Zeebe Broker does not start

Tags: zeebe

I am new to Zeebe. I am getting the following error on starting up Zeebe on my mac.

```
[exporter] [0.0.0.0:26501-zb-fs-workers-1] ERROR io.zeebe.util.actor - Actor failed in phase 'STARTED'. Continue with next job.
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: WORKFLOW_INSTANCE_RESULT
at io.zeebe.exporter.proto.RecordTransformer.<clinit>(RecordTransformer.java:113) ~[?:?]
at io.zeebe.hazelcast.exporter.HazelcastExporter.recordToProtobuf(HazelcastExporter.java:138) ~[?:?]
at io.zeebe.hazelcast.exporter.HazelcastExporter.export(HazelcastExporter.java:130) ~[?:?]
at io.zeebe.broker.exporter.stream.ExporterDirector$RecordExporter.export(ExporterDirector.java:390) ~[zeebe-broker-core-0.20.3.jar:0.20.3]
at io.zeebe.util.retry.BackOffRetryStrategy.run(BackOffRetryStrategy.java:51) ~[zeebe-util-0.20.3.jar:0.20.3]
at io.zeebe.util.sched.ActorJob.invoke(ActorJob.java:77) ~[zeebe-util-0.20.3.jar:0.20.3]
at io.zeebe.util.sched.ActorJob.execute(ActorJob.java:43) [zeebe-util-0.20.3.jar:0.20.3]
at io.zeebe.util.sched.ActorTask.execute(ActorTask.java:169) [zeebe-util-0.20.3.jar:0.20.3]
at io.zeebe.util.sched.ActorThread.executeCurrentTask(ActorThread.java:134) [zeebe-util-0.20.3.jar:0.20.3]
at io.zeebe.util.sched.ActorThread.doWork(ActorThread.java:118) [zeebe-util-0.20.3.jar:0.20.3]
at io.zeebe.util.sched.ActorThread.run(ActorThread.java:96) [zeebe-util-0.20.3.jar:0.20.3]
```

I am working with *zeebe-hazelcast-exporter-0.9.0* & ***zeebe-broker-0.20.3.***

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the latest stable version ([0.23.3](https://github.com/zeebe-io/zeebe/releases/tag/0.23.3)) in order to use the hazelcast exporter v0.9.0.

In the docker compose of the hazelcast exporter you can also see that this uses 0.23 https://github.com/zeebe-io/zeebe-hazelcast-exporter/blob/master/docker/docker-compose.yml